# Timer delay doesn't work properly

Tags: java, graphics, timer, delay

EDITTED POST:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Examp{
JFrame field;
JPanel squares[][] = new JPanel[10][6];

public Examp(){
    field = new JFrame("Football Game");
    field.setSize(600, 800);
    field.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 6));

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            squares[i][j] = new JPanel();
            if (j == 2 || j == 3)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                    squares[i][j].setBackground(Color.RED);
                else if (i == 9)
                    squares[i][j].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                else
                    squares[i][j].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            }
            else
            {
                squares[i][j].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            }
            field.add(squares[i][j]);
        }
    }

    field.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    field.setVisible(true);
}

public void place(int i,int j){
    ImageIcon ballIcon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Pamvotis\\Desktop\\Project\\img\\icon.png");
    JLabel ball = new JLabel(ballIcon);
    squares[i][j].add(ball);

    field.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    field.setVisible(true);
}

public void clear(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            squares[i][j].removeAll();
        }
    }
    field.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    field.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Examp football = new Examp();
    football.place(2,3);
    Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          football.clear();
          System.out.println("happened");
        }
    });
  timer.setRepeats(false);
  timer.start();

}
```

}

So I have edited and tried to simplify the code so you can understand what I am asking better I apologize about before.

Basically what I want is to clear the field from all icons after 1 sec (I want to make a football game so I'm using this to see how it would work on a bigger scale where I would remove everything after each round to add the new positions). My problem is that the the method  clear() doesn't seem to get executed when it is in the Timer (if I do it outside it gets executed just fine). My System.out.println(...)  gets executed just fine as well in the Timer with the proper delay so I really don't get what the problem is. Can anyone help me?

Comment: When should the football field be cleared?

Comment: When ever an action is fired? or when a certain time is reached?

Comment: For better help, create and post a valid [mcve]. Please read the link before posting.

Comment: And this is a Swing GUI, correct? You're displaying a GUI by calling the Game class? Note that you're making us do a lot of guessing here.

Comment: I apologize for all the problems before I am new at this but thats not an excuse. Nothing else had graphics this is the only part of the code that has them and I just need the football field to be cleared so in the bigger project I could refill it and such

Answer (score 1):

The `clear(...)` method is in fact very likely executed, and if you put a println within it, you'll know for sure. The question is, is it executing on the correct object?

I'm guessing that your Game class has its own Graphics object (a terrible class name by the way since it clashes directly with the `java.awt.Graphics` class, and that's the one that needs to have its state changed. A likely solution is to give Game a method that allows outside classes the ability to change its state.

For better answers though, please post a better more informative question, one with more pertinent code.

Comment: You are right the clear() probably does get executed because I put a println with it and it works but I cant understand why the football field doesnt get cleared. I updated my question I hope its better for you to understand now sorry for the missing information before..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the better is to made field int counter expample int counter =1; and in timer task you can decrease counter by 1. so counter will have new value 0. And somewhere where you need that you can check does counter have value 0 if yes you can call your method football.clear();

Update:

```
   public int counter=1;

   *********

   Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         counter--;
     }
   });
 timer.start();
}

***********

if(counter==1){
  football.clear();
  System.out.println("happened");
}
```

Comment: I tried that but the compiler says counter would have to be final and when I declare that as final for some reason it doesnt change from 1 to 0 after...

Comment: Because it is final and then it can't be changed.

Comment: I tried while making the variable as static and even tho it changes now the field still doesnt get cleared and I dont understand why. Is there a problem where I call the method or ..?

Comment: `public static int counter=1;`

Comment: Yes I did that but the field was only cleared after I minimized and reopened the window .. do you think the problem might be with the method and not the timer?

Comment: the best is to make method for timer this way you are make, and call it in constructor. try that

Comment: I tried putting the place method in the timer to see if there would be a problem there as well but it worked.. I will try what you said with the timer in the clear method and hopefully that can make it work